# External jquery script not working

Tags: jquery, external

I have read all relevant articles on this subject and none of the solutions apply to me.

As the title indicates, I have an external jquery script that is not working. I originally developed the script inside the php document, where it worked perfectly, but after I moved it to an external file it stopped working altogether. None of the proposed solutions touched on in other similar questions apply.

1. The jquery library source preceeds my script in the code.
2. The path provided to the script is correct.
3. The script is bound to the $(document).ready event

One strange fact might provide a clue, but I have no idea how to interpret it: In the resources tab of Chrome developer tools, the external script is shown to be blank. There is no 404 error, so the script was found and returned by the server, yet it shows it as being completely blank (unless you double-click to open the script in a separate tab.)

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menuBrowser li").click(function() {

        if ($(this).children().is(':visible')) {
            $(this).children().hide('slow');
        } else if ($(this).children().is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).children().show('slow');
        }    
    })
})​
```

**Update:** I just copied the contents of the external script back into the main file and it did not work. I reverted to an earlier save state with the script inline and it worked. I then copied and pasted that working script back into an external file and it worked. Something must have happened when I copied and pasted the script to the external file the first time, but heck if I know what it was.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: What happens when you open the script in your browser?

Comment: I would add an alert or a console.log to the top of the script and see if you can get that to show up. Then you will be sure that the script is at least loading and executing.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am not receiving any javascript errors in the Chrome Developer Tools console.

Comment: When I open the script in my browser it is displayed in plain text.

Comment: Does it work in firefox?

Comment: @Phil Cross
Here is the url:
http://www.industrialmerchants.com/industrialMerchants/

I'm developing the template and menu interfaces, so it's just a facade at the moment.

Comment: @Robert Niestroj
It does not work in Firefox either.

Comment: try removing typeface. I have a feeling it is replacing that menu and your events are being thrown away. Does that change anything?

Comment: No change unfortunately.

Comment: I just copied the contents of the external script back into the main file and it did not work. I reverted to an earlier save state with the script inline and it worked. I then copied and pasted that working script back into an external file and it worked. Something must have happened when I copied and pasted the script to the external file the first time, but heck if I know what it was.

Comment: Innnnnteresting... I haven't been around SO long enough to know how you should handle this question. Could a more senior member please advise on how Daniel should handle this? Should he post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

well, just for grins, I ran this through jshint.com with the JQuery option turned on of course and it said this:

```
Line 2: $("#menuBrowser li").click(function(){

Missing "use strict" statement.

Line 10: })

Missing semicolon.

Line 12: })

Missing semicolon.
```

I hope this helps,

Comment: The semicolons were a huge oversight. I'm surprised the script worked at all, even in an inline context.

However, adding them did not fix the problem, nor did adding a "use strict"; statement at the top of the file.

Comment: @DanielArant those semicolons shouldn't matter. its good to have them, but they definitely aren't causing the problem. see my comment on the OP.

Comment: If the paths are all correct, then the only suggestion I can think of is to clear out the browser cache and close/ reopen the browser. I've had many JS problems where the browser wasn't getting the changes I made.

Comment: No dice. A fresh browser with clean cache yields the same result.

Comment: ok can you use the page with firefox and use firebug to see what the jquery is doing? hopefully firebug will give you an error code or something to go on...

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy this from jsFiddle or a similar website? If so, you most likely have some invisible characters in there.

In order to remove those invisible characters, retype the whole script by hand (don't copy-paste), and the characters should be removed.

Check the console for problems as well. Firefox and WebKit browsers (Google Chrome, Safari) both have reasonably good JavaScript error logging programs.

Why not try emptying the cache? Could always help as well.

White pages usually mean a server error, if there is a server-side script involved.

There's nothing much I can help you with now, unless you provide more information.

Cheers! :)